# SPSS Modeler first not observation

Tags: spss-modeler

How do we get first not observation in SPSS Modeler. I have ordered my variable in ascending order by ID . And Could you please let me know what function do we use to get not equal value in SPSS Modeler. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you need? I understood that you are trying to analyze the missing cases.

To filter missing cases: add a filter node (option include or exclude - depending on the type of analysis) and with the code below:

var = undef or var = '$null$' or var =''